# Why isn't there a 'the' before 'industry in America'?

Tags: grammar, definite-article

The following sentence is from *[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/microcosm#:%7E:text=What%E2%80%99s%20happened%20to%20us%20is%20a%20microcosm%20of%20what%E2%80%99s%20happened%20to%20industry%20in%20America.)*.

> What’s happened to us is a microcosm of what’s happened to industry in America.

The industry here is restricted to America. So, why isn't there 'the' before 'industry in America'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Industry' with zero article means *all* industry, or industrial activity, as a whole.

If you added an article, it would sound like you were talking about a particular industry, such as the manufacturing industry, or the car industry, for example.

The same is true with 'business'. You can ask someone "*how's business?*" It doesn't mean the person's business as an entity, or the assets that might be associated with their business, but just their business activities in general.